# Pundit context access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

An application defines a pundit user according to its context of shop

```
  def pundit_user
    CurrentContext.new(current_user, @shop)
  end
```

In practice, the following policy for `Contact class`

```
  def initialize(user, contact)
    @user = user
    @contact = contact
  end

  def create?
    user && (user.admin? || user.editor? || (user.id == contact.user_id))
  end
```

does not work as the user attibutes cannot be accessed.

The following error is returned for the `admin` attribute of user, nor, *upon removing the first two conditions*, does not access the user's id.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<CurrentContext:0x0000000114537220  
@user=#<User id: 830861402, email: "shopkeeper@mail.co", name_last: "string", name_first: "string", admin: false, editor: false [...] dconne: nil>,  
@shop=#<Shop id: 1039309252, name: "[...]
```

An attempt to alter the initialization invoking the current context

```
  def initialize(current_context, contact)
    @user = user
    @shop = shop
    @contact = contact
  end
```

fails where @shop is not recognized `NameError: undefined local variable or method` shop' for #<ContactPolicy:`

How can the @user and @shop values be accessed to establish a working policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set up `CurrentContext` class so you can use it inside the policy classes:

```rb
class CurrentContext # <= FIXME: the name is not very descriptive
                     #           maybe `AuthorizationContext`

  # NOTE: create reader methods to 
  #       get @user and @shop variables outside of this class.
  attr_reader :user, :shop

  # NOTE: to make a clear distinction here. `initialize` arguments
  #       just hold the values that you pass to `new` method.
  def initialize(user_argument, shop_argument)
    @user = user_argument
    @shop = shop_argument
  end
end
```

`pundit_user` method is what *Pundit* uses to [initialize](https://github.com/varvet/pundit/blob/v2.2.0/lib/pundit/authorization.rb#L67) a policy class:

```rb
def pundit_user
  CurrentContext.new(current_user, @shop)
end

# authorize(record)
# |
# `->Pundit.authorize(pundit_user, record, query, policy_class: policy_class, cache: policies)
#    |
#    `->Pundit.policy(pundit_user, record)
#       |
#       `->ContactPolicy.new(pundit_user, record)
```

Inside the policy class, just use `CurrentContext` as any other object:

```rb
# @contact or Contact-.
#                     |
# pundit_user--.      |
#              v      v
def initialize(user, contact)
  # NOTE: `user` and `contact` are just local variables
  #       actual names are irrelevant.
  
  # NOTE: `user` is an instance of `CurrentContext` 

  @user = user.user # get the user
  @shop = user.shop # get the shop

  @contact = contact
end
```

To make it obvious what we should get in the initializer, just rename the argument:

```
def initialize(user_context, contact)
  @user = user_context.user
  @shop = user_context.shop
  @contact = contact
end
```

Comment: thoughtful explanation of the mechanics of pundit inner workings.